# pass and modify char array[][] in function C

Tags: c, arrays, string

i have a char array[][] and i want to use it at a void function and modify some values.

```
char teams[MAX_TEAMS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1] = { "Olympiakos", "P.A.O.K.", "Panathinaikos", "Panionios"};
```

(MAX_TEAMS and MAX_NAME_LENGTH are #defined integers at the start of the programm.
And i was to use a void function to modify the array.How do i have to define the function,how am i goin to pass the array from main?and how am i goin to use it in the function??

```
void print_teams(char [][]);  (?????)

int main(){
    char teams[MAX_TEAMS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1] = { "Olympiakos", "P.A.O.K.", "Panathinaikos", "Panionios"};
    print_teams(teams);
}

void print_teams(char teams[MAX_TEAMS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1]){
     strcpy(teams[0], "Milan FC");  
}

I am looking for a way of declaration so that any modifies inside the void function to be saved at array teams.
Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: `strcpy(teams[0],"Milan FC");`

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags. C++ is not C! 2) What does your C book state you don't understand? We are no tutoring service, declaring functions and how to use parameters will be explained in every C book.

Comment: ok with strcpy....but what about the pass on the function...??and sorry about the tags...

Comment: `void print_teams(char teams[MAX_TEAMS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1]);` In other words, just copy the function definition and put a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Way to do this :

```
void print_teams(char [][MAX_COL_SIZE]);
```

you can find more info in the below link :
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html

and use `strcpy(teams[0],"Real Madrid");` instead of using "="

Comment: This is identical to what the OP got. In fact his code is better, since it can lead to increased type safety if you check the code with static analysing tools.

Comment: still not what i want...i want the array that goes to the function to "save" the changes that are inside the function.

Comment: it will save the changes check it out.

Comment: you have called it correctly just execute it and enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function `teams[0]` is an array. You can't assign to an array, only *copy* to it:

```
strcpy(teams[0], "Milan FC");
```

Also note the use of *double* quotes.

Lastly for the function prototype, just copy the declaration you have for the function definition.

Comment: i want help with the declaration of function void.....its not working as "void print_teams(char [][]); "